# How to remove that space in Guys?

Tags: space

```
name = "Hello Guys"
for i in name:
    if " " in i:
        i.split(" ")
        print()
    print(i,end="")
```

> Hello
> Guys

Answer (score 0):

Try the string `str.strip()` function. It removes trailing whitespace from strings. Your code would then look something like:

```
name = "Hello Guys" 
for i in name: 
    if " " in i: 
        i.split(" ") 
        print() 
    print(i.strip(),end="")
```